# OpenModelica: Input in second level for FMU export

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, fmi

I have a model, create an FMU out of it, and want to import it in to python.

Having inputs on the first canvas works, and transferring them to the blocks which are used works, too.

Because of the architecture of the python code, i need to have the prefix for the inputs as for the rest of the block.

I made a minimal example:

```
package testi
  model source
    Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.SignalVoltage signalVoltage annotation(
      Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, 36}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground ground annotation(
      Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {48, 22}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.Pin pin annotation(
      Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {100, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {100, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput u annotation(
      Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, 108}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = -90), iconTransformation(origin = {0, 108}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = -90)));
  equation
    connect(signalVoltage.n, ground.p) annotation(
      Line(points = {{10, 36}, {48, 36}, {48, 32}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(signalVoltage.p, pin) annotation(
      Line(points = {{-10, 36}, {-20, 36}, {-20, 0}, {100, 0}, {100, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(signalVoltage.v, u) annotation(
      Line(points = {{0, 48}, {0, 48}, {0, 108}, {0, 108}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  end source;

  model base
  testi.source source1 annotation(
      Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-42, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  testi.measurement measurement1 annotation(
      Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {44, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  equation
    connect(source1.pin, measurement1.pin) annotation(
      Line(points = {{-32, 40}, {34, 40}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  end base;

  model measurement
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Resistor resistor annotation(
      Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-24, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.Pin pin annotation(
      Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-100, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-100, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground ground annotation(
      Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {30, -28}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  equation
    connect(pin, resistor.p) annotation(
      Line(points = {{-100, 0}, {-34, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(resistor.n, ground.p) annotation(
      Line(points = {{-14, 0}, {30, 0}, {30, -18}, {30, -18}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  end measurement;
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")));
end testi;
```

Trying to create the FMU causes the error: Undetermined equation system: 23 equations, 24 variables, although i would provide the input "source.u" via python. If I create an additional Input directly in the base model and connect it to the input of the source, it works, but then i do not have the same prefix "source.u" in my python code, which i would really like to have.

Does anyone know a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Define a second input `u` inside model `base` and connect it to the input of `source.u` so you only have inputs on the top level of the FMU.
Now the FMU will happily compile and you should be able to change `source.u` from outside.

```
model base
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput u;
  testi.source source1;
  testi.measurement measurement1;
equation
  connect(source1.pin, measurement1.pin);
  connect(u, source1.u);
end base;
```

Comment: In our python architecture, everything is capsuled in classes. So if we want to provide an input for example to our "inverter1", the input would be automatically labelled from the python class inverter1 as "inverter1.u", and not only "u". Cancelling the class name out of the input works, but is slightly annoying and confusing, especially when we have several different inverters. So giving inputs directly "to the middle of the model" with the prefix of the block where they are used would make the python code way more readable :-)